# Disappearing {% csrf_token %} on website file

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, pythonanywhere

When I wanted use my registration form in my site, I get ERROR 403: "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." In source of this website I realised that  is missing. This is part of view-source from my site:

```
<div style="margin-left:35%;margin-right:35%;">
<fieldset>
<legend> Wszystkie pola oprócz numeru telefonu należy wypełnić </legend>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        <p><label for="id_username">Login:</label> <input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" required/></p>
<p><label for="id_email">Email:</label> <input id="id_email" name="email" type="email" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_password1">Hasło:</label> <input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_password2">Powtórz hasło:</label> <input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_phone">Telefon:</label> <input id="id_phone" maxlength="20" name="phone" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_log_on">Logowanie po rejestracji:</label><input id="id_log_on" name="log_on" type="checkbox" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Rejestracja"><input type="reset" value="Wartości początkowe">
    </form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I was surprised of that, because in my files on Pythonanythere this fragment of code is present.

This is part of my file register.html on Pythonanythere:

```
<div style="margin-left:35%;margin-right:35%;">
<fieldset>
<legend> Wszystkie pola oprócz numeru telefonu należy wypełnić </legend>
    <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Rejestracja"><input type="reset" value="Wartości początkowe">
    </form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong that my webpage don't see this piece of code? It is seamed on server but on webpage view-source It isn't.

EDIT:
This is view, which render my template:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FormularzRejestracji(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
        )
        user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        user.save()
        if form.cleaned_data['log_on']:
            user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            login(request, user)
            template = get_template("osnowa_app/point_list.html")
            variables = RequestContext(request, {'user': user})
            output = template.render(variables)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            template = get_template("osnowa_app/register_success.html")
            variables = RequestContext(request, {'username': form.cleaned_data['username']})
            output = template.render(variables)
            return HttpResponse(output)

else:
    form = FormularzRejestracji()
template = get_template("osnowa_app/register.html")
form = FormularzRejestracji()
variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
output = template.render(variables)
return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Can you show the view that renders this template?

Comment: Is the SECRET_KEY in settings.py is generated everytime you restart your server ?

Comment: How do you initialize your rendering context?

Comment: I restart my server a lot of times and it didn't work :(

Comment: Could you show your middelware settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass a plain dict and the request object to `template.render()`, not a `RequestContext`. The template engine will convert it to a `RequestContext` for you:

```
template = get_template("osnowa_app/register.html")
context = {'form': form}
output = template.render(context, request)
```

Right now, the `template.render()` function sees a dict-like object as the first argument, but no request as the second argument. Without a request as the second argument, it converts the dict-like `RequestContext` into a plain `Context` object. Since the `Context` object doesn't run context processors, your context is missing the csrf token.

Alternatively you can just use the [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), which returns a `HttpResponse` object with the rendered template as content:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def register(request):
    ...
    return render(request, "osnowa_app/register.html", {'form': form})
```

This particular case is also being discussed in [ticket #27258](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27258).

Answer (score -2):

CSRF token gets included in HTML form by calling `hidden_tag` function on your form object.

For example check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/srahul07/6507758), line number 6. This is how you add form and it's elements in jinja.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question.

Comment: This is Django template language, not Jinja2. `{% csrf_token %}` is correct.